# rSpec3 doubles in around block

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I get the following error when I run my test

*The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the
per-test lifecycle is not supported.*

```
describe 'foo_bar'
  require 'sidekiq/testing'
  around(:example) do |example|
    allow_any_instance_of(FooRunner).to receive(:next_tick)
    Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
      example.run
    end
  end

  it ' ....' do
  end

end
```

How do I work around the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the double in `before(:example)` hook.

```
  around(:example) do |example|
    Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
      example.run
    end
  end

  before(:example) do |example|
    allow_any_instance_of(FooRunner).to receive(:next_tick)
  end
```